# javascript: unreachable code in for iterator

Tags: javascript, collections, visual-studio-2015

Ok, im feeling kinda stupid with this one.

I am trying to define a function that checks wether an item is already present inside the listbox items collection (could be any collection actually)

here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function canInsert(listbox, item)
        {
            if (item == null)
                return true;

            var itemCount = listbox.GetItemCount();

            for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
            {
                var nitem = listbox.GetItem(i);
                if (nitem.value === item.value)
                    return false;
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

using VS 2015 CE, it says i++ is unreachable code. HOW AND WHY ?

Comment: move `return true;` out of the loop - you need to check all items before saying "yes" to `canInsert` and to avoid `undefined` result in case of empty `listbox`

Comment: The i++ is evaluated only after the first loop is completed. And the `return true;` stops that from happening.

Comment: Yea, i just spotted that after i posted this. how stupid of me. I would downvote myself if i could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Igor said, when you return true at the end of your for loop, JS will exit the function immediately returning the value 'true'.

You can execute the for loop you currently have, and if your if statement condition is met, false will be returned and the function will be exited. After your for loop, if the condition is never met, true will be returned. Your code should look like the below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function canInsert(listbox, item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return true;

        var itemCount = listbox.GetItemCount();

        for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
        {
            var nitem = listbox.GetItem(i);
            if (nitem.value === item.value)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```